# docker-compose connect server/client containers from different devices on LAN

Tags: docker, flask, raspberry-pi, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose for deploying a server/client application on different devices on my local network. My setting is the following:

- In my docker-compose.yml file, I have a service called 'server', which depends on two additional services ('database' and 'web'). These three services are running on the same device and are able to connect successfully with each other. The 'server' service deploys a Flask-based API which should ideally be waiting for requests from other devices in the same LAN.
- In the very same docker-compose.yml file, I have a service called 'client', which runs an application that should be deployed on more than one device in the same LAN. The 'client' service, independently from the device where it is running, should be able to send requests to the 'server' service, which is on a different device in the same LAN.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  outside:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.220.0/24

services:

  client:
    build: ./client
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Madrid"
    command: >
      sh -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime &&
      echo $TZ > /etc/timezone &&
      nmap -p 8080 192.168.220.220 &&
      python -u client/main_controller.py"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    networks:
      outside:


  server:
    build: ./server
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Madrid"
    command: >
      sh -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime &&
      echo $TZ > /etc/timezone &&
      python -u server/main_server.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # host:container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
      - web
    networks:
      default:
      outside:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.220.220

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    #command: ./database/run_db.sh #mysqld --user=root --verbose
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # host:container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      default:


  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./interface:/www
      - ./interface/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      default:
```

I am using the python requests library to send requests from 'client' to 'server' using the following url:

```
http://192.168.220.220:8080
```

My issue is, that when I run both containers, 'client' and 'service', on the same device [deviceA], they are able to successfully communicate.

But when I run the containers on different devices ('service' on a computer with Mac OS X [deviceA], and 'client' on a Raspberry Pi [deviceB], both connected to the same LAN using wi-fi), the 'client' is not able to reach the specified IP and port.

To test if the device is able to reach the IP:port combination I use the following command right after running the 'client' service:

```
nmap -p 8080 192.168.220.220
```

Which gives the following output on [deviceA]:

```
client_1    | Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-03 12:22 Europe
client_1    | Nmap scan report for raspberry_escape_controller_server_1.raspberry_escape_controller_outside (192.168.220.220)
client_1    | Host is up (0.00012s latency).
client_1    | PORT     STATE SERVICE
client_1    | 8080/tcp open  http-proxy
client_1    | MAC Address: <mac_address> (Unknown)
client_1    |
client_1    | Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.71 seconds
```

and the following one on [deviceB]:

```
client_1    | Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-03 13:24 CET
client_1    | Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
client_1    | Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.78 seconds
```

**----------- [EDIT 1] -----------**

As suggested by **DTG** here is the output of netstat command on [deviceB]:

```
root@a9923f852423:/code# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.220.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.220.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

It looks like it is not able to see [deviceA], which should be 192.168.220.220

Comment: check https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#prevent-docker-from-manipulating-iptables as having `iptables` set to `false` in /etc/docker/daemon.json could give similar results

Comment: I changed the parameter to false on both machines but does not seem to make any change.

Comment: It should not be set to `false` unless you want to handle routing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that even though the service is up and running in your [deviceA] , there is some kind of firewall not allowing external connections to it from outside .

Maybe you should need to check the Firewall configuration at [deviceA].

**ROUTING ISSUES**

If it is a Routing issue you should see the routing table in hostB with

```
netstat -nr
```

And see that a valid route exist to hostA

If no valid route exist you should add one with

```
sudo route add -net hostA_IP/MASK gw HOSTB_DEFAULT_GATEWAY
```

INTER DOCKERS COMUNICATIONS

After you create the network, you can launch containers on it using the docker run --network= option. The containers you launch into this network must reside on the same Docker host. Each container in the network can immediately communicate with other containers in the network.

Read more about understanding docker communications:
[See docker documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communication-between-containers)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked its firewall but it looks like it is disabled. You can see a screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/J7ZjMtb).

Comment: And can you connect to your macbook from other host or point in your network ?

Comment: Using telnet as you suggested:

Running from inside the 'client' container of [deviceA] it is able to reach the host:

root@ccaba82bb26e:/code# telnet 192.168.220.220 8080
Trying 192.168.220.220...
Connected to 192.168.220.220.

Although when running from inside the 'client' container on [deviceB], it is not able to establish a connection:

root@a9923f852423:/code# telnet 192.168.220.220 8080
Trying 192.168.220.220...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

Comment: Ah that is the issue (NO ROUTE TO HOST) , it means that the deviceB does not know how to reach deviceA , it is a routing issue

Comment: You should look the routing table in hostB , the Ip and also likely the firewall that should be allowing  outgoing connections initiated from inside hostB . You can use : `code` netstat -nr
ifconfig `code` in hostB to check the status of your neetwork

Comment: I added some comments to above to troubleshoot the rooting issues . You can put the output of "netstat -nr" command  to see if a route to hostA exists

Comment: I edited the end of my question with the output of netstat command. The thing is, when adding the new route, what should exactly be in my case <hostA_IP/MASK> and <HOSTB_DEFAULT_GATEWAY>?

Comment: Before going further what is the IP of HostB? Im asking because the output of netstat -nr from hostB looks like the route is correct. HostA has Ip  192.168.220.220. You can find both ip with command "ifconfig" .

Comment: Are you aware of this ?I added this to my response: After you create the network, you can launch containers on it using the docker run --network=<NETWORK> option. The containers you launch into this network must reside on the same Docker host. Each container in the network can immediately communicate with other containers in the network. as per [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communication-between-containers)